# Facebook integration

Tags: facebook, web, integration, profile

is it possible to let a person hook their Facebook account into my website? Like they register on my website, then they can click hook into Facebook and it allows them to login, then if somebody clicks on their profile in my website, it shows their Facebook feed?

EDIT:
Also is there a tutorial on it? If so, please link me, because I cannot find anything on it.

Thanks - Julian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About Facebook Login, this is probably the best source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/v2.0

It also includes code samples, you can either use FB.login in a user event (typically a mouse event) to login manually, or you can use the Login Button Plugin: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/v2.0

About getting the Facebook feed: You would need to authorize users with the "read_stream" permission and access it with the Graph API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.0

This would be the endpoint for the feed: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/feed

The easiest way to use the Graph API is via JavaScript or PHP:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/4.0.0